# ¿"Patriota" o "patriotero"?

Tags: diferencias-entre-palabras

Según la RAE, *[patriotero](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SBYkThb)* es:

> Que alardea excesiva e inoportunamente de patriotismo.

Esto me da a entender que es un patriota estilo héroe americano.

Pero este artículo dice algo completamente distinto: https://www.prensalibre.com/opinion/patriota-o-patriotero/

Al final, ¿cuál es la diferencia entre *patriota* y *patriotero*?

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, Edu. Parece una pregunta interesante, pero recuerda que debe ser autocontenida. Si el enlace que has puesto falla nos quedamos sin saber qué querías decir. Cita las partes más importantes del artículo aquí, y sobre todo danos toda la información que puedas acerca de tu duda específica. Consulta la sección [ask] para más información.

Comment: El artículo plantea una extensión o reinterpretación del concepto de *patriotero*. No veo dónde está la consulta lingüística; creo que el propio artículo lo explica bastante bien. Luego, se puede estar de acuerdo o no.

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo la pregunta, el mismo texto que enlazas lo dice muy claro:

> La RAE define patriotero como un adjetivo utilizado para quien alardea excesiva e inoportunamente de patriotismo. **Coloquialmente se ha convertido en una forma irónica para denominar a los falsos patriotas**, que pretenden enmascarar como algo bueno lo malo.

Comment: La definición de la RAE y la que implica el resto del artículo no coinciden del todo, me parece. De hecho tampoco coinciden con la que le damos en Argentina (donde *patriotero* está influida por *[patotero](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SAset5G)*).